# Theme layout is different after copy

Tags: wordpress

I new to wordpress, dealing with customization of current theme.
I cannot create a child theme of this theme, as this one is already a child theme of another theme.

What I did is that I copied theme folder from wp-content/themes, changed name of this folder and changed Theme name in style.css -> expecting that this theme will work exactly the same as the previous one.

Although there are some major differences when I activate the new one:

**Original:**

[image: Original header]

[image: Original footer]

**Copied theme:**

[image: Copied theme header]

[image: copied theme footer]

It seems to me like some part of customization of the original theme is missing in the database.

So my question is: Apart from theme folder, what else (and how) do I have to change for my copied theme to be exactly the same as the previous one?

Thanks for any help in adavance.

Comment: Hi,
If you're using the theme in the same WordPress installation then no need to copy any other folder than the theme. If it is a different installation, then there is a chance that some elements might be from the plugins too.

Answer (score 0):

good time,
To solve this you need to paste the custom CSS code used on the new website.
If your previous website is online, just do so by pressing the Q (Inspect Element) key in the Firefox browser to access the source and copy the CSS inline codes.

Comment: I don't think that's it, it's not CSS, but the whole html structure is different, for example text in the footer, that is deffinetely not CSS